# Why does fs.readFile return null for first fetch call?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a simple function to return a pdf file on my server which works as expected but not the first time the page loads. The first time I try to download the file, the server console log shows me it's there, but the React page console has null. If I click on the download link again, the file contents are returned. Can someone help me please?

React function that calls getDocByLoc (which is itself called by a button click)

```
  async function fetchInvoice(fileLocation) {
    setInvoiceStatus('loading');
    setInvoice(await invoiceService.getDocByLoc({ location: fileLocation }));
    setInvoiceStatus('succeeded');
    downloadFile(invoice);
  }

  // download file
  function downloadFile(invoice) {
    if (invoiceStatus === 'succeeded') {
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(invoice);
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'test.pdf';
      a.click();
    }
  }
```

React fetch code

```
function getDocByLoc(location) {
  return fetchWrapper.getDocument(`/invoices/document`, location);
}
```

fetchWrapper code

```
function getDocument(url, location) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      ...authHeader(url),
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(location),
  };

  return fetch(`${AppSettings.serverEndpoint}${url}`, requestOptions).then(
    handleResponseForDocuments
  );
}
```

Node file reader code

```
function getDocumentByLocation(req, res, next) {
  const { location } = req.body;
  fs.readFile(location, (err, data) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
    console.log('data: ', data);
    res
      .contentType('application/pdf')
      .send(
        `data:application/pdf;base64,${new Buffer.from(data).toString(
          'base64'
        )}`
      );
  });
}
```

[image: React console]

[image: Node console]

Comment: What does `fetchWrapper.getDocument` look like?

Comment: Sorry, added the code now @JonasOsburg

Comment: > ```return fetch(`${AppSettings.serverEndpoint}${url}`, requestOptions)```
you always work with response there not result, why not onwrap text() or json() in fetcher ? like
```return (await fetch(`${AppSettings.serverEndpoint}${url}`, requestOptions)).json()``` I think handleResponseForDocuments has a problem

Comment: @zb' Thank you for your suggestion but I don't have a problem with the code the second time I run it or for any other time I use it. If I want to view the pdf, it works; it's just when I want to download it that it comes back as `null`.

Comment: most probably you use upper scope variable somewhere and not wait for file read resolution, before using it,  so 1st time is null, because it set as null, next time you see prev request result.

ah - also you have no return in error handler, data can be null if error only,  so check this.

Comment: which node version do you use ? in case of error node 16.11 returns undefined to data in case of error, so there should be no null ever.